# Excel: Arrange text cells with maximum distance

Tags: excel

In my Excel-Sheet (see below) are names of different places: 5x Alpen, 7x Big Sur, 2x Britany...

I would like to automatically order these places in a way that the names of one place would be as far away from each other as possible. E.g. between 2 Alpen cells will be as many other places as possible. Is that possible? If yes: How to do so?

PS: In my full list there are a few hundred of cells. Therefore, an automated solution is strongly preferred.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help @CallumDA. I changed the question to a single question. Now it should be a possible question to ask, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that your input range looks like left column and you want to get the right column (I have completely ignored the 2. point):

[image]

So, pretty much these are the steps you need to take:

- take the values from `Range("A1:A47")` and put them in a dictionary;
- sort the dictionary by value;
- start looping through the dictionary, searching for the next free position (`GiveMeNextFreePosition()`). Once it is located, assign the value of the dictionary to array finalRange;
- loop through the array finalRange and write the values there to the next column with the offset function;

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()
    'with a reference for MicrosoftScriptingRuntime
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim initialRange As Range
    
    Set initialRange = Range("A1:A47")
    For Each myCell In initialRange
        If dict.Exists(myCell.value) Then
            dict(myCell.value) = dict(myCell.value) + 1
        Else
            dict.Add myCell.value, 1
        End If
    Next myCell
    'sort the dictionary
    Set dict = SortDictionaryByValue(dict, xlDescending)
    Dim finalRange As Variant
    ReDim finalRange(initialRange.Count)
    Dim myKey   As Variant
    For Each myKey In dict.Keys
        Dim cnt         As Long
        Dim placesLeft  As Long
        While dict(myKey) > 0
            dict(myKey) = dict(myKey) - 1
            cnt = GiveMeNextFreePosition(finalRange, myKey)
            finalRange(cnt) = myKey
        Wend
    Next myKey
    
    Dim rowCounter  As Long
    rowCounter = initialRange.Cells(1, 1).Row - 1
    For Each myCell In initialRange.Offset(0, 1)
        myCell = finalRange(rowCounter)
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Next myCell        
End Sub

Public Function GiveMeNextFreePosition(ByRef arr As Variant, _
                                       ByVal myInput As String) As Long
    
    Dim cnt     As Long: cnt = -1
    Dim reserve As Long
    
    For cnt = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(cnt) = vbNullString Then
            reserve = cnt
            If cnt <> LBound(arr) Then
                If arr(cnt - 1) <> myInput Then
                    GiveMeNextFreePosition = cnt
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                GiveMeNextFreePosition = 0
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next cnt
    
    GiveMeNextFreePosition = reserve
    
End Function
```

---

The [Sort Dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) Function:

---

```
Public Function SortDictionaryByValue(dict As Object _
     , Optional sortorder As XlSortOrder = xlAscending) As Object

    On Error GoTo eh

    Dim arrayList As Object
    Set arrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim dictTemp As Object
    Set dictTemp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Put values in ArrayList and sort
    ' Store values in tempDict with their keys as a collection
    Dim key As Variant, value As Variant, coll As Collection
    For Each key In dict

        value = dict(key)

        ' if the value doesn't exist in dict then add
        If dictTemp.Exists(value) = False Then
            ' create collection to hold keys
            ' - needed for duplicate values
            Set coll = New Collection
            dictTemp.Add value, coll

            ' Add the value
            arrayList.Add value

        End If

        ' Add the current key to the collection
        dictTemp(value).Add key

    Next key

    ' Sort the value
    arrayList.Sort

    ' Reverse if descending
    If sortorder = xlDescending Then
        arrayList.Reverse
    End If

    dict.RemoveAll

    ' Read through the ArrayList and add the values and corresponding
    ' keys from the dictTemp
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each value In arrayList
        Set coll = dictTemp(value)
        For Each item In coll
            dict.Add item, value
        Next item
    Next value

    Set arrayList = Nothing

    ' Return the new dictionary
    Set SortDictionaryByValue = dict

Done:
    Exit Function
eh:
    If Err.Number = 450 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 100, "SortDictionaryByValue" _
                , "Cannot sort the dictionary if the value is an object"
    End If
End Function
```